# how to set Click Event on different size grid in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development.I want tile like grid User interface for my application ,the grids will be of different size holding image and text and when user will click on the single grid I want to navigate to different page.I searched alot but couldn't find any good example.if anyone can suggest something it will be of great help.I am not able to decide which type of control I have to use.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow the "Your Question/ Your Code/ Your Exception" template and reformat your question. Thanks

Comment: Why not just attach an event to the content in the grid ... and when the user taps, show the new page?

Comment: I got the solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354499/tap-event-for-a-rectangle-with-text-and-image-on-top-of-it  Now I am Confused that if I want to have Five grids then I will have to create five different grids?